# SQL: Turn a row into a column (and include column names in a new column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I'm busy writing a claims provider class to be used in a Security Token Service.

User permissions are read from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database:

```
SELECT A, B, C, ..., X FROM Permissions WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

would give me a single row, for example:

```
A B C ... X
1 0 1     1
```

it would be much easier to have this data in the form

```
Permission Value
A          1
B          0
C          1
...
X          1
```

Since the actual table contains dozens of columns, I'd prefer to be able to do the transposition "dynamically" without really having to type up any column names by hand.

It feels like the PIVOT/UNPIVOT functions and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view are what I need, but I can't quite figure out what to do.

Any ideas for a query that would do this?

PS. I guess if push comes to shove, I'd just stick the result set in a DataTable and iterate over the columns in code to generate the user claims, but I'd like to find out if the above approach is possible first :)

Comment: Are you thinking about `join` perhaps?

Comment: Depending on how many variables you have, you could just simply use a `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have an `UNPIVOT` function available (you did not specify RDBMS) then you can use `UNION ALL` (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4d91/1)):

```
select 'A' as Permission, A as Value
FROM Permissions
WHERE UserId = @UserId
UNION ALL
select 'B' as Permission, B as Value
FROM Permissions
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

If you have an unknown number of columns in sql-server, then you can use dynamic sql and your code would be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @colsUnPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colsUnPivot = stuff((select ','+C.name
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('Permissions')
            and C.name != 'UserId'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select permission, value
    from
    (
        select *
         from permissions
         where userid = '+@UserId+'
    ) x
     unpivot
     (
        value
        for permission in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec(@query)
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4d91/4)

Comment: Unpivot works beautifully. Unfortunately I've just discovered I can't use it because of the compatibility level of the database (which is beyond my control), so I'll go with union all. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Unpivot indeed.

```
   select Permission, Value 
   from (Select * from Permissions where UserID = @userID) s
   unpivot (Value for Permission in ([a],[b],[c],...,[x])) u
```

If you must have dynamic columns, then construct the above query using dynamic SQL and `sp_executesql`, or in your c# code (with appropriate due care and attention).

But presumably you know what the columns are?  Perhaps it would be possible to store the permissions in the normalised form of your results in the first place?